FastAPI sending data (POST) with double quotation yields an JSON decode error
I am trying to send malformatted JSON string to the FastAPI endpoint. However, I get the 422 Error: Unprocessable Entity. Since I don't have a way to control the input data, how can I resolve it?
# Define the prompt template
prompt_template = """
The following JSON is malformatted. Please correct the syntax errors and ensure that all nested JSON strings are properly formatted as JSON objects within the overall JSON structure. Provide only the well-formatted JSON without any additional text:

{malformatted_json}
"""

# Create a PromptTemplate
prompt = PromptTemplate(input_variables=["malformatted_json"], template=prompt_template)

# Initialize the LLM
llm = Replicate(
    model="meta/meta-llama-3-70b-instruct",
    model_kwargs={"temperature": 0.75, "top_p": 0.9, "max_new_tokens": 5000},
)

# Create an LLMChain with the prompt and model
chain = LLMChain(llm=llm, prompt=prompt)

# Define Pydantic model for input
class JSONInput(BaseModel):
    malformatted_json: str

# Define Pydantic model for output
class JSONOutput(BaseModel):
    corrected_json: str

# Initialize FastAPI app
app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/")
async def root():
    return {"message": "Revolutionize Your JSON Handling with JSONFixer Pro!"}

@app.post("/correct_json", response_model=JSONOutput)
async def correct_json(input_data: JSONInput):
    try:
        # Run the chain with the malformatted JSON
        corrected_json = chain.run({"malformatted_json": input_data.malformatted_json})
        return JSONOutput(corrected_json=corrected_json)
    except Exception as e:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail=str(e))

# Endpoint to check the health of the API
@app.get("/health")
async def health():
    return {"status": "ok"}

Here is the curl code.
curl -X 'POST' \
  'http://127.0.0.1:8000/correct_json' \
  -H 'accept: application/json' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{"malformatted_json": "{\"essay_task\": \"<p class=\\\"text-muted\\\">Due to unforeseen circumstances, you are unable to meet the deadline for an assignment. Write a letter to your course instructor requesting an extension.</p>\\r\\n<p class=\\\"text-muted mt-2\\\">In your letter:</p>\\r\\n<ul class=\\\"list-disc list-group-flush\\\">\\r\\n<li>State the name of the course and the assignment.</li>\\r\\n<li>Explain the reason for needing an extension.</li>\\r\\n<li>Request a specific extension length and propose a new due date.</li>\\r\\n</ul>\\r\\n<p class=\\\"text-muted mt-2\\\">Write at least 150 words.</p>\\r\\n<p class=\\\"text-muted mt-2 font-italic\\\">Dear Professor [Instructor\\\'\''s Last Name],</p>\", \"essay_answer\": \"Dear Professor [Instructor\\\'\''s Last Name],\\r\\n\\r\\nI am writing to you in regards to requesting an extension for the due date of the upcoming [Assignment name] assignment in your [Course name] class. The assignment is due on [Original due date], unfortunately [Explain the reason for needing an extension, e.g., I recently became sick and fell behind in my coursework, a family emergency required my attention]. Because of this unforeseen situation, I am unable to complete the assignment up to the standard I expected by the original due date.\\r\\n\\r\\nI would be grateful if you could grant me an extension of three extra days. This would allow me to finally catch on the missed coursework and dedicate more time to research and writing.\\r\\n\\r\\nI already completed a little bit on the assignment [Mention any progress made on the assignment] and I am confident that I can submit a high-quality assignment by the new due date, which would be [Proposed new due date].\\r\\n\\r\\nThank you for your understanding and consideration. I apologize for any inconvenience this may cause.\\r\\n\\r\\nSincerely,\\r\\n\\r\\n[Your Name]\", \"text\": \"\\n\\nHere is the marking result in JSON format:\\n\\n``\\n{\\\"errors\\\":{\\\"Task Achievement\\\":{\\\"Error\\\":\\\"The test taker has adequately addressed the task, but there are some inconsistencies in tone and details. The format is generally appropriate, but some parts may be unclear or irrelevant.\\\",\\\"Example\\\":\\\"To improve, the test taker should focus on clearly explaining the purpose of the letter and ensure that all key features/bullet points are adequately covered.\\\"},\\\"Coherence and Cohesion\\\":{\\\"Error\\\":\\\"The test taker has arranged information and ideas coherently, but there is some lack of overall progression. Cohesive devices are used effectively, but there may be some faulty or mechanical use.\\\",\\\"Example\\\":\\\"To improve, the test taker should work on creating a clearer overall progression and using cohesive devices more effectively to link ideas.\\\"},\\\"Lexical Resource\\\":{\\\"Error\\\":\\\"The test taker has used an adequate range of vocabulary, but there are some errors in spelling and/or word formation. Less common vocabulary is attempted, but with some inaccuracy.\\\",\\\"Example\\\":\\\"To improve, the test taker should focus on using more precise vocabulary and ensuring that spelling and word formation are accurate.\\\"},\\\"Grammatical Range and Accuracy\\\":{\\\"Error\\\":\\\"The test taker has used a mix of simple and complex sentence forms, but there are some errors in grammar and punctuation. These errors rarely reduce communication.\\\",\\\"Example\\\":\\\"To improve, the test taker should work on using a wider range of sentence structures accurately and ensuring that grammar and punctuation are correct.\\\"}}\\n}\\n\\nHere is the justification for the marking:\\n\\n<b>Task Achievement: 6</b>\\n\\nThe test taker has adequately addressed the task, but there are some inconsistencies in tone and details. The format is generally appropriate, but some parts may be unclear or irrelevant. The test taker has presented a clear purpose, but the tone is not consistently formal throughout the letter. Key features/bullet points are adequately covered, but some details may be irrelevant or inaccurate.\\n\\n<b>Coherence and Cohesion: 6</b>\\n\\nThe test taker has arranged information and ideas coherently, but there is some lack of overall progression. Cohesive devices are used effectively, but there may be some faulty or mechanical use. The test taker has used transitional phrases to link ideas, but the connections between paragraphs are not always clear.\\n\\n<b>Lexical Resource: 6</b>\\n\\nThe test taker has used an adequate range of vocabulary, but there are some errors in spelling and/or word formation. Less common vocabulary is attempted, but with some inaccuracy. The test taker has used some formal vocabulary, but there are some mistakes in word choice and collocation.\\n\\n<b>Grammatical Range and Accuracy: 6</b>\\n\\nThe test taker has used a mix of simple and complex sentence forms, but there are some errors in grammar and punctuation. These errors rarely reduce communication. The test taker has attempted to use subordinate clauses, but there are some mistakes in sentence structure and punctuation.\\n\\nOverall, the test taker has demonstrated a good effort in completing the task, but there are some areas that need improvement, such as tone consistency, vocabulary accuracy, and grammatical accuracy.\"}"'

I get the following response.
{
  "detail": [
    {
      "type": "json_invalid",
      "loc": [
        "body",
        694
      ],
      "msg": "JSON decode error",
      "input": {},
      "ctx": {
        "error": "Invalid \\escape"
      }
    }
  ]
}


There is a problem with single quotes in this area: .......[Instructor\\\'\''...... The first two quotes are escaped: but in JSON single quotes should not be escaped with a backslash, which is invalid in JSON. The error message "Invalid \ escape" refers to this anomaly in the JSON. Like always with JSON: you should not fix malformed JSON. The only correct action is to contact the provider and tell them they produce invalid JSON.

Actually, you can create a middleware that will correct input data
